# Получить 20 случайных чисел от 1 до 1000, но чтобы эти числа не повторялись

Tags: javascript

Как на JS сделать такую задачу. Нужно получить `20` случайных чисел от `1` до `1000` но чтобы эти случайные числа не повторялись. Как сделать такое? 
Все это дело должно работать в цикле.
Вот пример половины кода.

```
var random_start = 1; // От какого генерировать
var random_end = 1000; // До какого генерировать

    allСycles = 20;
    for(countCycles=1;countCycles<=allСycles;countCycles++){
    alert ("Случайное рандомное и уникально не повторающиеся число от 1 до 1000");
    }
```

**Пробовал по подсказкам так, но бывает числа повторяются**

```
var random_end = 1000;
allСycles = 20;
    for(countCycles=1;countCycles<=allСycles;countCycles++){

        var test = Math.floor(Math.random()*(random_end+1)+1);
        alert(test);

    }
```

Comment: Для ясности постановки задачи, вот как в Питоне это сделать: `import random; result = random.sample(range(1, 1001), 20)`

Comment: @Crantisz: я специально JS в заголовке оставил, для людей которые как автор вопроса используют это имя, а не javascript (вопросы должны использовать ту терминологию, которую используют люди с подобным вопросом—поэтому вопросы-дубликаты не удаляются на сайте: разные люди могут один и тот же вопрос задать, используя разные слова). В ответе/комментарии вы можете упомянуть корректную с вашей точки зрения терминологию, но терминологию автора вопроса следует сохранять.

Comment: На SO не принято перегружать заговок метками: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3480/Следует-ли-включать-метки-в-заголовок-вопроса/

Comment: JS не знаю, но предполагаю, что по аналогии с другими языками можно поступить очень просто. Перед циклом заводите массив из 1000 элементов и обнуляете его. Получаемое случайное число (оно же у вас от 1 до 1000) используете как индекс элемента данного массива. Если там 0 -- ОК, заносите в массив 1 и используете это число. Если там уже 1 просто повторяете итерации выборки очередного случайного. Выход из цикла модифицируете до достижения нужного (у вас 20) количества.

Comment: @Crantisz Метка здесь javascript. Она автоматически добавляется в заголовок, поэтому, если это слово не часть предложения, то его можно было бы убрать, но "javascript" (буквальная строка) не равна "JS" (в одном слове 10 букв, в другом 2). Если в поисковик вбить "JS что-то", то автоматически не обязан найтись "JavaScript что-то" вопрос, поэтому следует оставить JS, чтобы облегчить поиск для людей, которые эту терминологию используют.

Comment: @jfs любой современный поисковик синонимизирует JS и JavaScript. И даже Java Script. Легко проверить - поищите "Книги и учебные ресурсы по JS site:ru.stackoverflow.com" в гугле, яндексе или бинге и посмотрите на подсветку. Дописывание JS, как и дописывание "Питон" в вопросы по Python, ничем не облегчает поиск.

Comment: @PashaPash: Сравните: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8+%D0%B8+%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B+%D0%BF%D0%BE+JS и http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8+%D0%B8+%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B+%D0%BF%D0%BE+javascript

Comment: Я начал обсуждение на мете, связанное с переименованием: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4751/javascript-%D0%B8-js-%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5/4752#4752 давайте оставим комментарии к этому вопросу в покое

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Использую библиотеку [Lodash](https://lodash.com/)

```js
console.log(_.shuffle(_.range(1,1001)).slice(0,20))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Без нее:

```js
var random_start = 1; // От какого генерировать
var random_end = 1000; // До какого генерировать

allСycles = 20;

var array= []

for(i=random_start;i<=random_end;i++){
   array.push(i)
}

for(countCycles=1;countCycles<=allСycles;countCycles++){
    console.log(array.splice(Math.random()*array.length,1)[0])
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Нет, этот файл не на сайте. Он используется у меня в другой среде, там нет возможности внешние файлы подключать.

Comment: @Анатолий Вы можете скачать эту библиотеку и подключить _локально_

Comment: Ксожелению нет такой возможности. Это я макрос пробую сделать, в нем нет возможности подключать внешние файлы или библиотеки.

Comment: @Crantisz , для варианта с lodash можно и `shuffle` + `slice`

Comment: @br3t, спасибо, сократил код

Answer (score 8):

Ещё один вариант, бережный к памяти и вычислительным ресурсам (особенно для больших диапазонов значений).

```js
const range = 1000000; // максимальное значение (1..1000000 включительно)
const count = 10;      // кол-во требуемых чисел

let m = {};
let a = [];
for (let i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
  let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * (range - i));
  a.push(((r in m) ? m[r] : r) + 1);
  let l = range - i - 1;
  m[r] = (l in m) ? m[l] : l;
}

console.log(a);
```

Не требует предварительного создания и заполнения большого массива, кол-во итераций цикла соответствует кол-ву генерируемых чисел (нет перебора значений при коллизиях).

Как это работает?

Допустим нам нужно выбрать три числа из ряда 0..9 включительно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выбираем случайный индекс от 0 до 9, к примеру выпадает 3:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь, чтобы число 3 больше не попадалось, считаем его использованным, и переносим на его место последний элемент из ряда (9):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь у нас девять элементов, среди которых опять выбираем случайный, ставим на его место последний и т.д.

Т.к. требуемых на выходе чисел относительно немного, то запоминаем только перестановки (для остальных элементов, значение просто равно их индексу). Для этого используется js-объект m (ключами являются позиции в ряде, а значениями - значения).

Comment: Неплохо, правда ценность буфера неоднозначна. Но инкремент может быть неоптимизирован, см. [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/625580) :)

Answer (score 5):

## VanillaJs с ES6

*На основе алгоритма `range/shuffle/slice`*
*не подходит для очень больших диапазонов значений*

```js
{
 let from=1, to=1000, n = 10;
 let result = [...Array(to-from+1).keys()].map(i=>i+from) // range
   .reduce((arr, elt) => (arr.splice(Math.random() * (arr.length + 1), 0, elt), arr), []) // shuffle
   .slice(0, n); // slice n

 console.log(result)
}
```

---

Пояснения:

range: `[...Array(to-from+1).keys()].map(i=>i+from)`

- `Array(to-from+1)` - массив необходимой длинны
- .keys - получаем ArrayIterator индексов
- `[...ArrayIterator]` - конвертируем его в массив
- `.map(i => i + from)` - добавляем каждому элементу минимальное значение

shuffle: `.reduce((arr, elt) => (arr.splice(Math.random() * (arr.length + 1), 0, elt), arr), [])`

Просто с помощью `reduce` строим новый массив, вставляя каждый новый элемент в случайную позицию

---

## Оптимизированный range

```js
{
  class Range {
    constructor(start, end) {
      this.start = start;
      this.end = end;
    }
    includes(num) {
        return this.start <= num && num < this.end;
      }
      [Symbol.iterator]() { // Для for (el of range);
        let i = this.start;
        return {
          next: () => ({
            value: i,
            done: ++i > this.end
          })
        };
      }
    length() {
      return this.end - this.start;
    }

    sample(count) {
      if (count > this.length()) {
        throw new Error('Не хватает элементов');
      }
      let selected = {};
      for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        let num;
        do {
          num = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length()) + this.start;
        } while (num in selected);
        selected[num] = 1;
      }
      return Object.keys(selected).map(Number);
    }
  }
  let r = new Range(1e9, 1e10);
  console.log(r.includes(1e9 + 50));
  console.log(r.includes(1e9 - 50));
  for (let i of new Range(5, 8)) console.log(i);
  console.log(r.sample(3));
  console.log((new Range(1, 5)).sample(4)); // always all [1,2,3,4]
}
```

Comment: Слишком длинно для гольфа.

Comment: При чём тут гольф? Просто функциональщина.

Comment: Для "просто функциональщины" тут не хватает разъяснений что вообще происходит.

Comment: Добавил разъяснений

Comment: Т. е. для генерации 1 числа из 10 знаков нужно сделать массив `1000000000..9999999999`?

Comment: Да, думаю для этой задачи пришлось бы пересмотреть решение. :) Алгоритм моего ответа ничем не отличается от принятого. Тот же `range/shuffle/slice`

Comment: @Other, специально для вас, добавил реализацию получше.

Comment: Я счастлив :) Но ООП много. Заказываю оптимизированный вариант в виде функциональном.

Comment: Думаю, от запихивания метода sample в `reduce` он не станет функциональнее)) Там от ООП - 2 переменные

Comment: 1- Зачем вы используете `while (!num in selected)` вместо `while (num in selected)`? 2- защиту от бесконечного `r.sample(2)` где `r = Range(1,1)` можно добавить. 3- если [выборка больше определённой доли исходного диапазона](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f71868bfe6e226993a4a69edbcc5720340f5ce3d/Lib/random.py#L318-L338), то shuffle+slice вполне эффективно. 4- лучше правую границу не включать в Range.

Comment: 1, 2 исправил, 4 - спорно, дело привычки, 3 - won't fix =)

Comment: [E.W. Dijkstra объясняет (в 1982)](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html) почему правую границу не следует включать. Не стоит ошибки Бейсика повторять из 60-х годов прошлого века.

Comment: Причина только в вездесущей +1 в `this.end-this.start+1`, я правильно понял? =)

Comment: есть ещё как минимум одна вариация - `Range(start, length)`

Comment: 4 - убедил, сменил интерфейс)

Comment: @Other поревьюйте мой вариант, если не сложно

Answer (score 0):

Смысл в том, что мы на начальном этапе рассчитываем диапазон от которого в процессе отнимаем текущее значение + предыдущие, тем самым уменьшая диапазон из которого будет формироваться рандом. А прибавляя к полученному значению предыдущие значение мы делаем невозможность повторения числа.

```js
const generateRangeRandomArray = (start, end, length) => {
  let result = [];
  
  let ratio = Math.round( (end - start) / length );
  
  let current = NaN;
  let prev = 0;
  
  for(let i = 0; i < length; i++){
    current = Math.round( Math.random() * (ratio + ( ratio * i - prev ) ) );
    
    prev += current;
    
    result.push( prev );
  }
  
  return result;
}

console.log( generateRangeRandomArray( 1, 1000, 10 ) ); //
```

Comment: Наверное стоит уточнить, что получается ряд по возрастанию значений.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian А при генерации рандома это плохо? Ведь если нужно перемешанный массив, то это совсем друга история. Не стоит смешивать две разные задачи в одну. И я считаю что возрастание, как и максимально равномерный рандом, это плюс.

Answer (score 0):

Без ES6, vanilla. Честно говоря, просто наконец нашел применение `do... while`, хоть в календаре день отмечай.

```js
var i = 0,
    arr = [],
    count = 20,
    diff,
    curr,
    limits = [0,1000];

diff = limits[1] - limits[0];
while( i++ < count  && (diff >= (count - 1))){// В случае, если количество чисел на выходе превышает максимальное количество уникальных
  do{
    curr = Math.floor(Math.random() * (diff + 1) + limits[0]);
  } while ((arr.indexOf(curr) != -1));
  arr.push(curr);
}
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int [] Array = new int[20]; 
        for(int i = 0; i < Array.length;i++) {
            if(i ==0) {
                Array[i] = (int)(Math.random()*1000+1); continue;}
            else if(i != 0) {
                Array[i] = (int)(Math.random()*1000+1);
            }           
            for(int j = 0; j<i;j++) {
                if(Array[i] == Array[j]) {
                    i--;
                }               
            }           
        }
```

дико извиняюсь ... I mean '\t' and '\n' you can do for youself.

Comment: Последнея фраза, что вы имеете в виду?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getRandomNumbersInRange(min, max, count) {
    let result = [];

    while (result.length < count) {
        const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
        if (result.indexOf(randomNumber) === -1) {
            result.push(randomNumber);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(getRandomNumbersInRange(1, 1000, 20));
```

Создание массивов и их перемешивание крайне ресурсоемко. Предлагаю свой вариант, с очень простым принципом работы. Мы генерируем случайное число, и помещаем в массив если такого числа в этом массиве еще нет. И повторяем это действие, пока в массиве не будет нужного количества случайных чисел из диапазона.

Преимущества:

1. "честная" генерация нескольких случайных чисел в заданном диапазоне.
2. Не создает ничего лишнего, соответственно потребляет минимум ресурсов ЭВМ (особенно памяти).

Недостатки:

1. При каждом добавлении нового числа в массив, мы должны проверять его на уникальность. (чем больше чисел нужно сгенерировать, тем это дороже)
2. Сколько будет повторов мы точно не знаем (числа ведь случайные). А каждый повтор это лишняя итерация цикла.

На практике для 20 случайных чисел в диапазоне от 1 до 1000, более 5 'дублей' при запуске функции более 1 000 000 раз я не получал.

**И тем не менее, это не надежное решение! Точно сказать сколько итераций цикла будет в итоге не возможно! Поэтому ниже предложу немного более сложный, но надежный вариант.**

```js
function getRandomNumbersInRange(min, max, count) {
    let randomNumbers = [];

    while (randomNumbers.length < count) {
        randomNumbers.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min);
    }

    let uniqueNumbers = new Set();

    randomNumbers.forEach(
        n => {
            if (!uniqueNumbers.has(n)) {
                uniqueNumbers.add(n);
                return;
            }

            let i = 1;
            while (true) {
                const more = n + i;
                if (more <= max && !uniqueNumbers.has(more)) {
                    uniqueNumbers.add(more);
                    return;
                }

                const less = n - i;
                if (less >= min && !uniqueNumbers.has(less)) {
                    uniqueNumbers.add(less);
                    return;
                }

                i++;
            }
        }
    );
    
    return [ ...uniqueNumbers ];
}

console.log(getRandomNumbersInRange(1, 1000, 20));
```

В этом решении мы генерируем заданное кол-во случайных чисел, и уже потом просто "уникализируем" дубли.

Найдя дубль, мы ищем ближайшее "не занятое" число, проверяя в цикле в большую и меньшую сторону от "дубля", на каждой итерации прибавляя единицу. Как только мы находим "свободное число" мы заменяем "дубль" им и идем дальше искать "Дубли". И так пока все числа не станут уникальными.

При таком решении мы можем точно вычислить количество итераций для худшего случая. Скорее всего есть более совершенный алгоритм для "уникализации", буду дальше копать в этом направлении.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Чисто для коллекции, вариант с использованием `Set`.

```js
function rndNumbers(min, max, count) {
  if (count > max - min + 1) throw "impossible";
  let set = new Set();
  while (set.size < count) {
    let num = (Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min) | 0;
    set.add(num);
  }
  return [...set];
}

console.log(rndNumbers(1, 1000, 10));
console.log(rndNumbers(10, 20, 11));
console.log(rndNumbers(100, 200, 1000));
```